# retriving data using relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables, `employees` & `employee_manager`.

employees : `id`,`name`

employee_manager : `employee_id`,`manager_id`

`id` of `employees` and `employee_id` of `employee_manager` are the same.

Both `employee_id` and `manager_id` are `id`s of `employees` from `employees` table.

The manager of a particular `employee` is found using `manager_id`. Now I want to view the name of the manager from `employees` table.

Comment: Are you saying `Employee` and `Managaer` model has `many-to-many` relationship? in that case `$employee = Employee::find(1); $managersOfEmployee = $employee->managers;` should retrieve the managers if relationships are defined.

Comment: There's no Manager Model I think, the manager itself is an employee

Comment: Employee and EmployeeManager are the models

Comment: i tried this in Employee Model

Comment: public function employee_manager(){
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\EmployeeManager', 'employee_id', 'manager_id');
 }

Comment: read this document, it could help you to make relation and use them very simple and fast. [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please add this on your Employee model

```
public function manager()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Employee', 'App\Models\EmployeeManager', 'employee_id', 'id', 'id', 'manager_id'));
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: thank you. It works. I'm getting the selected row in response. but have trouble displaying it. i think the result come as array.

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: while inspecting i'm getting the result like manager[...] -> 0:  {...} -> then id='1' name = 'emp'

Comment: ahh, yes I forgot inform you. you should use `->manager()->first()`

Comment: public function manager()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Employee', 'App\Models\EmployeeManager', 'employee_id', 'id', 'id', 'manager_id')->first();
}      right?

Comment: yes, or wherever you call the manager like `$employee->manager()->first()`